# Count php ones does not work

Tags: php, laravel

Hi there can someone help me
I have this code:

```
@foreach($questions as $question)
      <?php  $correct= $question->correct; ?>
      {{($correct == 1)}}
@endforeach
```

and it appears this `1 1 1 1 1` I want to `count` how many ones are there
I tried `count($correct ==1)` but does not work

Comment: `{{ $correct == 1 }}` will echo the result of the comparison `$correct == 1` so it will either be a `1` or empty no matter what `$correct` is.

Comment: This looks like the kind of thing that should be calculated before sending it to the display layer. is showing a counter display logic or business logic?

Answer (score 2):

Use `collect` to make [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections) with [where](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-where) and [count](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-count)

```
$count = collect($questions)->where("correct",1)->count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>
@foreach($questions as $question)
    <?php
    $correct = $question->correct;
    if($correct == 1)
    {
        $count++;
    }
    ?>
@endforeach
```

This creates a new variable `$count` and increments it, every time `$correct` is equal to 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to `check` that value equal to `1` and then `increment` your count:

```
<?php $count = 0;?>
@foreach($questions as $question)
      @if($question->correct==1)
         <?php $count++;?>
      @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
 @php $totalCorrect = 0; @endphp
 @foreach($questions as $question)
  @if($question->correct == 1)
   @php $totalCorrect++; @endphp
  @endif    
 @endforeach
 {{ $totalCorrect }}
```

**Explaination**

create a `$totalCorrect` variable and assign initial value to 0 then in foreach loop we check that if answer is correct then `$totalCorrect` variable value will increment with 1 and after foreach loop print counter variable, it will give you total correct answer's count.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this**

```
@php 
    $i==0; 
@endphp
@foreach($questions as $question)
    <?php  $correct= $question->correct; ?>
    @php 
        $correct == 1; 
        $i++; 
    @endphp
@endforeach

{{$i}}
```

Comment: the code only answers are discouraged. Better to add some details.